# refer or extract the elements of a particular level

Tags: r

Say I applied the cut function on `seq(15)` like this `cut(seq(15), 5)`

I would get a list of bins in which each element would fall.  What if I want to extract the members or elements of the third level?  How can I refer to the elements that would fall in the 3rd bin after cutting the sequence?

Addressing Arun's comment:I will provide the cut function a vector like this:  temp <- cut(seq(15), c(.9,4,8,12,15)).  I am looking for the elements of the seq(15) that would fall in the 3rd level. They are 9,10,11,12. There is already an answer that worked bellow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take 5 minutes to read [this stackoverflow article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)on how to write good question that gets answered. The pullets are, do your homework, be specific, make it relevant to others, and so forth. Also always good to include reproducible code.

Comment: It'd be useful if you could write the output you seek, since it is not quite clear to me from what you've written as to what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is poorly worded and somewhat ambiguous, but can use basic indexing for this:

```
temp <- cut(seq(15), 5)
temp[temp == levels(temp)[3]]
# [1] (6.6,9.4] (6.6,9.4] (6.6,9.4]
# Levels: (0.986,3.79] (3.79,6.6] (6.6,9.4] (9.4,12.2] (12.2,15]
```

Or, if you wanted the relevant values from `seq(15)`:

```
seq(15)[temp == levels(temp)[3]]
# [1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: That will bring in all of the NA values as well. Could also use `which(temp)==levels(temp)[3]` as the index.

Comment: seq(15)[temp == levels(temp)[3]] this worked fine, but what if I wanted to select more than one levels elements.  Like all three last levels.  I tried seq(15)[temp == levels(temp)[3:5]] but it didn't work?

Comment: @user2004820 you would have to replace `==` by `%in%`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `labels=F` to get

```
 cut(seq(15),5,labels=F)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Then

```
x <- seq(15)
> x[cut(x,5,labels=F)==3]
[1] 7 8 9
```